# gitk gives "argument list too long" error

Tags: git

I always got the "argument list too long" error when I try to use "gitk" to open the GUI of the history for some large repo. Even using "gitk -n" didn't solve the problem. Does anybody here have same issue? Thanks,

```
couldn't execute "git": argument list too long
couldn't execute "git": argument list too long
    while executing
"open [concat $cmd $ids] r"
    (procedure "getallcommits" line 47)
    invoked from within
"getallcommits"
    (procedure "readcache" line 80)
    invoked from within
"readcache file13"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $script"
    (procedure "dorunq" line 11)
    invoked from within
"dorunq"
    ("after" script)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? whats your comand? seems that you added too many arguments

Comment: My command is just "gitk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Argument list too long" is a kernel error when you pass in too many arguments on a command line.

Probably your repo contains something which causes `$ids` (I'm purely speculating here) to exceed the `ARG_MAX` limit of your platform.

This is basically a bug in Gitk, but if you can figure out which resource is causing this, you can probably work around the problem by limiting or pruning it somehow.

Comment: This appears to attempt to address the problem, or a similar one -- does your repo have a lot of tags?  http://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/tDVsZzg7/patch-fix-gitk-with-lots-of-tags

Comment: Though I guess the error message seems to allude to a repo with a lot of commits.

Comment: Yes. It's a big repo. It currently has 9K tags.

Comment: Ok. But even "gitk -n" can not limit the results?

Comment: Not finding that in the manual page, never used gitk so no direct experience ... Try checking out a shallow clone or otherwise limiting what ends up in the clone you are operating on.

Comment: I have this issue at Windows. It helps to limit number of tags and branches - fetch only what is needed, remove as it's merged, etc.

Answer (score 12):

I've found a workaroung [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/z8yWyVcAF04) and it worked for me: just remove `.git/gitk.cache` file.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me (macOS 12.6 French, system Git)

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to the answer above: If you are using **worktrees**, bear in mind that there are other `gitk.cache` files too, like so:

```
.git/worktrees/dev-2/gitk.cache
```

You may have to delete those too.